# How to fix black edge lines on blender Editor?

Tags: edges

[image]

I have this simple stairs model (it is a flat model, no smooth) if you see it has a black edge, how to fix it?

Comment: Without knowing more about your model it will be hard to tell how to fix it.

Comment: **Please don't close questions before giving the OP time to add more information**. @GerardoGonzalesCruz : Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your model. Describe how you created the model and show images in edit mode.

Comment: Hi again, yes here more info: my model is a simple stairs in fact it is a cube with array modifier for steps, I removed doubles, but when I move slowly into Blender editor viewport I can see edges with black lines as image top, my question is how fix it? It is flat, no smooth one material purple color in this case...